# AutoCompleteTextView: detecting when dropdown is dismissed and item is NOT selected

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I need to know when the user taps outside of the `AutoCompleteTextView` dropdown in order to dismiss it  (i.e. they dismiss the popup with selecting an item in the list).  I've setup the `setOnDismissListener()` as shown here:

```
    mAutoView.setOnDismissListener(new AutoCompleteTextView.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            CharSequence msg = "isPerformingCompletion = " + mAutoView.isPerformingCompletion() +
                    "   Item selected at = " + mAutoView.getListSelection();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

And an OnItemClickListener like this:

```
 private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // get selected item and pass it to result callback
    }
};
```

The `onDismiss` event fires before the `onItemClick` event, and unfortunately, neither the "isPerformingCompletion()" nor the "getListSelection()" methods return a value until the `onItemClick` event fires.

Can anyone suggest an approach to detecting a dismiss without a list selection?

Comment: What do you plan on doing in this situation? If you don't need fine-grained timing, you could employ a typical timing hack. `postDelayed()` a `Runnable` in `onDismiss()` for a modest delay period. Use `removeCallbacks()` in `onItemClick()` to cancel that `Runnable`. If the `Runnable` runs, you know that you did not receive the corresponding `onItemClick()` within the delay period. Reliability sucks for short delay periods. But since the actual events are handled by the `ListPopupWindow` inside the `AutoCompleteTextView`, I'm not sure that you have an option.

Comment: If the user taps out of the dropdown, I want to display a small dialog to explain alternatives for finding the item not listed.  I considered adding some kind of delay, as you suggested, but I fear that it won't be reliable.  I'm new to java and Android and didn't know how to do it, so thanks for cluing me into Runnable.  I think I'm going to tweak the UI  in or der to eliminate the need for instructions.  Might require an extra tap or two, but will hopefully be more intuitive.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Below piece of code will detect that if user dismiss the dropdown of autocompletetextview, Then onDismiss it will check the selected input using Geocode API, If it is having a result then selected input is valid otherwise input is not valid, So In that case, Entered text will be vanish in bit seconds.

```
mAutoView.setOnDismissListener {
    try {
        val fromLocationName = Geocoder(context).getFromLocationName(mAutoView.getText().toString(), 1)
        if (fromLocationName != null && fromLocationName.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Address valid")
        } else {
            mAutoView.setText("")
            Log.d(TAG, "Address not valid")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        mAutoView.setText("")
        Log.d(TAG, "Address not valid with Exception")
    }
}
```

Means you need a kind of validator in OnDismiss, That will check the input text is valid or not, Based on validation you can indicate to user that entered input is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

> AutoCompleteTextView: detecting when dropdown is dismissed and item is NOT selected

If I understood you well, you need to catch the event of dismissing the draopDown by touching outside of it instead of choosing an item.

For some reason, the `setOnDismissListener` doesn't work for me. I couldn't find a clue without touching the inner `ListPopupWindow` which get called on either event (item click or touch outside).

The event is differentiated by registering an inner `OnItemClickListener` listener to set the tag of the view to some value that indicates that `BY_ITEM_CLICK` ; if the tag is anything else; it will be considered a touch outside event.

Here is a custom `AutoCompleteTextView` that can be used for that:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import android.widget.ListPopupWindow
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView


class OnDismissAutoCompleteTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView(context, attrs), AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    interface OnMenuDismissListener {
        fun onTouchOutside()
        fun onItemClick()
        fun onBackPressed()
    }

    companion object {

        // set the tag to this value when an item is clicked to dismiss the menu
        const val BY_ITEM_CLICK = "BY_ITEM_CLICK"

        // set the tag to this value when the back is pressed to dismiss the menu
    }

    init {
        super.setOnItemClickListener(this)
    }

    var onMenuDismissListener: OnMenuDismissListener? = null

    private var consumerListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? = null


    @SuppressLint("DiscouragedPrivateApi")
    private fun getPopup(): ListPopupWindow? {
        try {
            val field = AutoCompleteTextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
            field.isAccessible = true
            return field.get(this) as ListPopupWindow
        } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun setupDismissListener() {
        getPopup()?.let {
            it.setOnDismissListener {

                when (tag) {
                    BY_ITEM_CLICK -> onMenuDismissListener?.onItemClick() // Menu dismissal Event of clicking on the menu item

                    BY_BACK_PRESSED -> onMenuDismissListener?.onBackPressed()

                    else -> onMenuDismissListener?.onTouchOutside() // Menu dismissal Event of touching outside the menu
                }
                // reset the tag for the next dismissal
                tag = null
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
        // Registering the mPopup window OnDismissListener
        setupDismissListener()
        return super.onPreDraw()
    }

    override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        tag = BY_ITEM_CLICK
        consumerListener?.onItemClick(p0, p1, p2, p3)
    }

    override fun setOnItemClickListener(l: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?) {
        // DO NOT CALL SUPER HERE
//        super.setOnItemClickListener(l)
        consumerListener = l
    }

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isPopupShowing)
            tag = BY_BACK_PRESSED
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
myAutoCompleteTV.onMenuDismissListener = object :
    OnDismissAutoCompleteTextView.OnMenuDismissListener {
    override fun onTouchOutside() {
        // Menu dismiss is due to touch outside event
        Toast.makeText(context, "touch outside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onItemClick() {
        // Menu dismiss is due to clicking on an item
        Toast.makeText(context, "item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "back pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```